# How does this If conditional work in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't understand how this line works:

```
    if user:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

I'm guessing the users.get_current_user() return a boolean? Then, if that is the case how can it get a .nickname() method?

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Type coercion, just like in PHP, JavaScript and some others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'll basically check if `user` is an actual object or `None`. If it's `None`, the code will go into the `else` block and redirect to a "create login" page.

Comment: Sorry for my C#-lingo, but is None the same as "Null". So it's checking if the user variable is null? But if that's the case, why would it go in that branch and access a method if it is null?

Comment: Indeed, `None` is the Python equivalent of `null` in other languages.

Comment: `None` is considered a false value in Python - thus, *if* `user` is `None`, the `else:` branch will be the one taken.

Comment: @Sergio: Exactly, 'None' is equivalent to C#'s null. But unlike C#'s strict requirement for a boolean in an if check, Python treats it as a "False" when it comes to boolean tests.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `users.get_current_user()` returns an object, or `None` if there is no current user.  Python interprets `None` as `False` in a conditional statement.

Note that testing for `None` this way is a bad practise, however. Other things like an empty list `[]` also evaluate to False.  Instead, the code should be modified to look like this:

```
    if user is not None:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Answer (score 2):

`users.get_current_user()` returns user' object or None if the user is not logged in. It is possible in python to check if the variable value is None like:

```
a = None
if not a:
  print "a values is None"
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns a user object, which could be None if there is no current user.  None is kind of like the python equivalent of NULL, and it evaluates as false in a conditional.